# Click ImageButton, take a picture and save photo in same imagebutton, even if leave application Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to build an application that when I click the ImageButton to take a picture that image becomes the default Imagebutton image forever until I change again.

I can take a picture and it becomes the ImageButton image. The problem right now is that when I leave the application the image disappears from Imagebutton.

Help me find a solution for that code, or showing me another code. Thanks

MainActivity

```
package com.example.camera;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.graphics.Bitmap;  
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.ImageButton;   

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton btnTackPic;
    Uri photoPath;


    static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnTackPic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE); 
        }
});
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                btnTackPic.setImageBitmap(photo);
                btnTackPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.camera.MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can do it, save your photo in a perticular location with the same name retrieve from it and set it as background

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to store your app data on the device. For images, the best and fastest solution if the to use an image caching technique. If you're looking for a fast solution, check the [default caching implementation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) provided by the devs. Once you have your bitmap ready, store it to your cache. Later on when the app reloads, first thing you do is to check your cache for any stored bitmaps, and load it into your imageButton.